# Specify inner glow the same way as Inner shadow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I'm illustrating a radio button element. 
When unticked I want the element to be perceived as being "descended" into the page, with a inner shadow at the top and a inner glow at the bottom.

The inner shadow does what I want to, adding a slight shadow in the top of the element, right beneath its border. The glow however is applied to the entire edge of the element, this is not what I want. As with the shadow only being in the top I want the glow to only be at the bottom.

How do I achieve this the easiest way, can it be done in the same effects step (without having to rasterize or make new selections in the layer)?

**Edit:** I've found that I can specify a inner glow in the bottom at the same time as I specify the inner shadow using the Brevel & Emboss effect. Then I could turn the shadow from B&E down to 0% opacity and only use the glow. It works, but it's not as "fool proof" as the drop shadow effect since you specify the angle in two dimensions in B&E whereas in drop shadow you only specify the angle in one dimension.

Comment: I think you've got some pretty good solutions in there. May I ask why you're against rasterizing the effects? You can also duplicate the shape, apply another style and then turn the fill to 0%.

Comment: @Johannes you're very right. I was merely interested to know if there was some quick and easy way of applying a positioned inner glow in the same way as applying the inner shadow. What you suggest, duplicating the layer setting the fill to 0% adding a white drop shadow and letting it go from the bottom (which I assumed was what you suggested) is indeed a very good solution to it. However, it's quite a few more steps than the simple apply of the drop shadow. I don't know, maybe I'm just being lazy... :-)

Comment: Can you send the screenshot how you want ?

Answer (score 1):

2 more step to your workflow: convert element to smart object and apply inner shadow with new angle.

Comment: true, but then the initial shadow is not editable any more.

Comment: it's editable inside smart object

Comment: Ok, that's pretty cool. A feature that I was unaware of, "inception of smart objectifying". It's still a bit more cumbersome than I would wish, but as a feature that I was previously unaware of this is great!